# How to kill the explorer.exe file explorer, but not the shell (in Python)

Tags: windows, winapi, ctypes

From my research, I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1005205/close-all-windows-file-explorer-windows-but-dont-kill-the-explorer-exe-shell) question, and it had the answer, but it wasn't in Python. The answer to that question was a program called nircmd.exe, which can be used to close "CabinetWClass". I know I can technically use os.system, but is there a cleaner way to do achieve the same result in Python without using nircmd.exe?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would have to reverse-engineer what NirCmd is doing. At a guess, it continuously calls [`FindWindowW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindoww) passing `L"CabinetWClass"` as the window class name. As long as it finds one, it sends a [`WM_CLOSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-close) message to it. Many things can go wrong with that, so this only serves as a starting point.

Comment: You should use Restart Manager API to restart Explorer in a clean/supported way: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/rstmgr/about-restart-manager not sure if there's python interop for this (it could be created obviously, but it's quite a work)